# Putting a DIV tag inside another DIV tag

Tags: html, alignment

I am pretty new to web design stuff but what I understood from DIV tag is that I it like a logical container for what ever is inside it and those thing will follow its rules..
so now I have an outer DIV tag defined as `<div style="margin-left: 10px;" >`and I have put some textbox, buttons, comboboxes inside it...now I also have a HyperLink that I want it to be there BUT I want this one to be at the right hand side , aligned to right , so I defined another DIV like `<div align="right">` and put the hyperlink insde this one. they are all still inside that other outer DIV tho. but it is not going to the right...what is wrong and how can I fix it?  I attached the picture, see I want it to be like this picture, at the right hand side of that combobox...

thanks all

[image]

Comment: It's more helpful if you put the actual markup in the question.

Comment: the whole file you mean? I put the DIV ones that I had used tho.

Comment: It is generally not good practice to use inline styles or the align attribute. You should be using external css stylesheets that are included with a <link> element in the <head> of the html document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you need to align inline element (your link tag) to the right, you can use `text-align` property of the style, and set it to right:

```
<div style="text-align:right">
  <a href="">blabla</a>
</div>
```

Comment: ok worked in FireFox .. the browser inside EClipse was not showing it so I thought it is not working. thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is no align.  Do you mean text-align?  That will affect inline elements within block level elements.

Comment: yes, got it... I am new to CSS, so I did not now about text-align, learned it now from the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="margin-left: 10px;">
    <p>Reason for Referral</p>
    <input type='text'></input>
    <div style="display:inline"><a href='#'>Not Found?</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its below the combobox becouse the text is too long to fit in the outer div? that would make it go one row lower.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like:

```
<div class='group'>
    <p>Reason for Referral</p><br/>
    <input type='text'></input>
    <div class='right'><a href='#'>Not Found?</a></div>
</div>
```

Then in css:

```
div.right {
    float: right;
}
```

You should get something close to the effect you want.

Comment: ok I used float:right and the label disappeared! cannot find it on the page!